# Issue accessing remote web server on Android Emulator

Tags: android, emulation

I am trying to create a testcase to test my web application in andriod browser on Android Emulator.
I followed all the steps shown in "https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/AndroidDriver".
But i am getting "HTTP Error 404 -- Problem accessing /context".

```
import junit.framework.TestCase;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.android.AndroidDriver; 

 public class TestAndroidWebDriver extends TestCase {

      public void testAndroid() throws Exception {

          WebDriver driver = new AndroidDriver();
          driver.get("http://server.com/context");
          String title = driver.getTitle();
          assertTrue("Got title: " + title, title.contains("Title"));
          driver.close();
          driver.quit();

     }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After Installing necessary packages and configuring Android Emulator, Restart your machine.
Connect to your VPN first and then start the Android Emulator and webdriver.
Make sure to use IP address, when you connect to intranet applications.

Comment: After restarting my Machine and using IP address for the URL, it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the "http://server.com/context" accessible from the emulator browser .
AndroidDriver not able to access the link.

Comment: Emulator browser can't access http://server.com/context and this is a intranet application and I can access all the internet applications